# Strip out harmful code but allow Iframe

Tags: php, iframe

I have a selfmade cmssystem where users can insert, edit and delete content. I would like to allow them to insert Iframes ( for video purpose, for sites like Vimeo and Youtube ).

I secured the output from my database to my website with htmlspecialchars. Offcourse it converts the IFrame to a string so the video isn't shown.

Is there a secure way to avoid this?

Comment: I don't think so. When I use strip_tags it removes the output. With htmlspecialchars it shows the code...

Comment: Use HTMLPurifier, which lets you specify what tags and attributes are to be considered safe.

Comment: Also possible using `strip_tags($text, '<iframe>');`